# Hit method from a nested method

Tags: angular, typescript

How do you hit a function from inside a separate embedded function in typescript?

What I'm trying to accomplish...in pseudo;

```
export class blah {

    functionOne(result) {
       // do stuff with the result of functionTwoChildMethod...
    };

    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode (paramObj, function (res, stat) {

       functionTwoChildMethod = () => {
         this.functionOne(result);
       };

    };
};
```

It appears doing `this.functionOne(result);` doesn't reach the scope of the class to the parent to fire off functionOne or something. So what am I missing? Thanks for any direction this has bothered me for longer than I care to share :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` will be crazy I know but try `that` ;)

```
export class blah {

    functionOne(result) {
       // do stuff with the result of functionTwoChildMethod...
    };

    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var that = this;
    geocoder.geocode (paramObj, function (res, stat) {

       functionTwoChildMethod = () => {
         that.functionOne(result);
       };

    };
};
```

`this` you are using is inside a scope where is don't have the functions you need but by using assigning it to `that` you can us the function you need ;)
it is all about variable scope

Comment: HA! Yes....that is not a logic I would have guessed! Thank you so much! If I could upvote as well I would but my rep is too low, but you have my thanks either way! :)

Comment: don't worry i am just happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

> So what am I missing

the wrong `this`.

## Fix

Use an arrow function

```
export class blah {

    functionOne(result) {
       // do stuff with the result of functionTwoChildMethod...
    };

    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode (paramObj, (res, stat) => { // Use arrow here

       functionTwoChildMethod = () => {
         this.functionOne(result);
       };

    };
};
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: I get the Uncaught TypeError: _this.functionOne is not a function
 error, still doesn't seem to find it?

Comment: @LearningNewStuff then you have more `this` wrongs than one. I've updated the answer using arrows liberally

Comment: Sorry no luck, perhaps my example was a little vague, would it matter functionTwo is an anonymous function from a const object? Please see my updated question example for more specifics, I'm trying to get outside of the new google instance anonymous function so I can report the API's results to another method.